# AngularJs, svg : handle rectangle rotation, drag, resize... easily?

Tags: angularjs, svg

We are working on an angular SPA which allow users to draw elements like rectangle, lines, elipses...

User must be able to rotate, drag, resize all those elements.
For that we use the snap BBox angles, to place some grips, to be able to resize for example.

All grips are so identified as NordWestPoint, NordEastPoint, SouthWestPoint, SouthEastPoint.

This is working fine if we don't use the rotation: drag and resize are working fine.

But as soon as we use rotate, for example to reverse a rectangle upside down, and then try to resize, the NordWestPoint is now in the SouthEastPoint place, and this is a mess, the resize is not working anymore and have some weird behaviour as the positioning functions return wrong results...

Is there any library that we can use, any pattern, any good practice, any example that someone can show to handle that easily?
Thx

Comment: you need to update handlers after rotation, flip etc..

Comment: I'm more likely looking for a brand new way to handle that, more than correcting existing code, as i think our code is too complex

Comment: better see raphaelJS. Snap is based on this.